# Solving polynomial equation systems in Coq

Tags: coq

I ended up with the following goal, which disappointingly wasn't solved by neither the tactics in *Psatz* nor *Omega*.

```
Require Import Psatz Omega.
Goal forall n n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6,
       n5 + n4 = n6 + n3 ->
       n1 + n0 = n2 + n ->
       n5 * n1 + n6 * n2 + n3 * n0 + n * n4 =
       n5 * n2 + n1 * n6 + n3 * n + n0 * n4.
intros.
Fail lia.
Fail omega.
```

Lazy as I am, I tested all combination of values up to 30, and it matched in all instances, so I think the goal is valid.

Is there some other way to solve this goal (preferably as automatically as possible)?

Also, when will `omega` and `lia` fail (for valid equation systems)?  I noticed to my surprise that `omega` didn't even  solve `a*b = b*a`.

EDIT:

It is possible to solve it with the `lia` tactic for `Z` integers after doing some manual substitutions.  (Doing the substitutions for `nat` does not work (!)) Can that be automated by some other tactic? And then I have to "port" the theorem back to `nat`...  How would I do that?

```
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z.
Lemma help:
  forall n n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6,
    n >= 0 -> n0 >= 0 -> n1 >= 0 ->
    n2 >= 0 -> n3 >= 0 -> n4 >= 0 ->
    n5 >= 0 -> n6 >= 0 ->

    n5 + n4 = n6 + n3 ->
    n1 + n0 = n2 + n ->
    n5 * n1 + n6 * n2 + n3 * n0 + n * n4 =
    n5 * n2 + n1 * n6 + n3 * n + n0 * n4.

  intros.
  Fail lia.
  assert (n5 = n6 + n3 - n4) by lia; subst n5.
  assert (n1 = n2 + n  - n0) by lia; subst n1.
  Fail omega.
  lia.
Qed.
Close Scope Z.
```

Comment: "... omega didn't even solve ab = ba" -- Multiplication is handled by omega but only goals where at least one of the two multiplicands of products is a constant are solvable. This is the restriction meant by “Presburger arithmetic” [[Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual024.html#sec697)]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers one part of the question.  Do you know why `lia` works for `Z` but not for `nat`?  And how would one "port" a theorem from `Z` to `nat`?

Comment: In `Z` it is true that `m - n + n = m` but in `nat` it is not the case (e.g. if `n > m`). So part of the problem might come from there...

Comment: But for example,  `n5 + n4 = n6 + n3` _implies_ `n5 = n6 + n3 - n4` (but the reverse is not true) so `n4` can't be larger than `n6+n3`.  Maybe the problem with `lia` is that `nat` isn't a proper ring (with a _minus_), but the statement should be true none the less, right?

Comment: It does imply it but it's not an equivalence so I can see why a (complete) solver would abstain from performing that step. And as the answer you have now accepted mentions, `nia` (which I did not know about) is indeed *incomplete*.

Comment: Funny that a "complete" solver doesn't find the solution, but an "incomplete" solver does.  What is the meaning of "complete/incomplete" in this case? "Only perform steps that don't risk throwing away solutions?" (but what's the use if the complete solver anyway says "no solution found"?)

Comment: **(1)** I'm surprised `lia` managed (after some nudging in the right direction) to prove the goal at all. Its domain is linear integer arithmetic(LIA), and the last equation is not linear. I hope I'm not mistaken about what LIA means in this context. **(2)** By the way, the two `assert`'s can be solved by `omega`. **(3)** And if you replaced the last `lia` of the last example with `ring`, the goal would be solved too. It's not surprising, because you did all the work: if you bring the goal to normal arithmetic form (with `ring_simplify`), you'll see that it's an identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `nia` will solve the goal. A quote from the Coq reference [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual025.html#sec706):

> `nia` is an incomplete proof procedure for integer non-linear arithmetic (see Section 22.6)

And since the equations are not linear, this will work (even in `nat_scope`):

```
Goal forall n n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6,
       n5 + n4 = n6 + n3 ->
       n1 + n0 = n2 + n ->
       n5 * n1 + n6 * n2 + n3 * n0 + n * n4 =
       n5 * n2 + n1 * n6 + n3 * n + n0 * n4.
intros.
nia.
Qed.
```

As for the `omega` part of the question:

> ... omega didn't even solve `a*b = b*a`

`omega` is based on [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), which is, by the way, decidable. An excerpt from the Coq [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual024.html#sec697):

> Multiplication is handled by `omega` but only goals where at least one of the two multiplicands of products is a constant are solvable. This is the restriction meant by “Presburger arithmetic”

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed.  It also worked for `Z`. I will mark this as anwered, but do you have any ideas about porting a function over `Z` (or `positive`) to `nat`? If you do I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: I have never really thought of it (promise to do it tomorrow). But do post the question anyway! You never know what people here can come up with. I've learned quite a bit from answers here.

Comment: I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293710/port-a-coq-lemma-over-z-to-a-similar-lemma-over-nat

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of "prototyping", using external SMT solvers in addition to Coq's procedures may also be a good idea.

A mature choice is the [`why3` tactic](http://why3.lri.fr/doc-0.81/manual011.html) (note: you'll need why3 head to work with Coq 8.5), but other options are possible such as [this](https://gmalecha.github.io/reflections/2016/03/16/coq-smt-check/)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.  One thing that disappointed me was this: "The current goal is then translated to Why3’s logic and the prover is called. If it reports the goal to be valid, then _Coq’s `admit` tactic is used to assume the goal._ "  I hoped that Why would create a trace that could be constructed back into a Coq proof, to not grow the amount of trusted code.  I've seen stuff like that be done for HOL proofs, but apparently this is not done by Why (at least not in the direction from Why to Coq).

Comment: Indeed, coq-smt-check (from the second link) with the Z3 solver works in the domain of real numbers (`R_scope`): `intros. smt solve; apply by_smt.` solves the problem. The plugin understandably fails in `nat_scope` or `Z_scope`.

Comment: @larsr yeah this is why I said for "prototyping". Keep in mind that SMT can solve huge goals with traces in the GiB. There are however solvers such as Zenon that produce traces, but I have no experience with them.